# Dynamic Date to be passed in getListItemChanges method

Tags: soap, wsdl, xquery

I am using the below code. It works perfectly.

```
<GetListItemChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>States At A Glance</listName>
<viewFields></viewFields>     
<since>2013-08-29T 19:52:52Z</since>
<contains></contains>
</GetListItemChanges>
```

I wanted the datetime in the since tag to be dynamic. So, I used the below xquery functions to calculate it:

```
declare variable $Y := fn:concat(fn:substring(fn:string(fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')),1,11), ' ', fn:substring(fn:string(fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P30D')),12,8), 'Z');
```

I tested the value of $Y, it is exactly - what I want.

But, when I substituted the date value with $Y, the code started erroring out:

```
let $soap-payload := ('<GetListItemChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>States At A Glance</listName>
<since>{fn:data($Y)}</since>
</GetListItemChanges>')
```

error message:

**axis2_svc_client_send_receive failed. Web Service returned a soap fault. 
Error type: XQuery Engine error. soap:ReceiverException of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown..**

Answer (score 0):

Your code as shown will not perform the substitution. The variable `$soap-payload` doesn't contain XML, but a string. XQuery expressions inside of a string will not be evaluated. If you remove the single quotes from `$soap-payload`, the XQuery expression will be evaluated.

If you need `$soap-payload` to be a string, you could build it through string concatenation, or you could serialize the XML. The mechanism for that depends on your XQuery processor (and version).

- XQuery 3.0: `fn:serialize()`
- MarkLogic Server: `xdmp:quote()`
- Saxon: `saxon:serialize()`

**Concatenation Examples**

*XQuery 1.0*

```
let $soap-payload :=
  fn:concat(
    '<GetListItemChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>States At A Glance</listName>
      <since>',
    fn:concat(
      $Y,
      '</since>
      </GetListItemChanges>'))
```

*XQuery 3.0*

```
let $soap-payload :=
  '<GetListItemChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
     <listName>States At A Glance</listName>
     <since>' || $Y || '</since>
   </GetListItemChanges>'
```

**Serialization Example**

```
let $soap-payload-xml :=
  <GetListItemChanges xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <listName>States At A Glance</listName>
    <since>{ $Y }</since>
  </GetListItemChanges>
let $soap-payload := fn:serialize($soap-payload-xml)
```